# Evaluation of $\beta$-reduction of $~\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)$

Tags: lambda-calculus

$$\begin{align}
\Delta&:= \lambda x ~.~x~x~x\\
\Delta\Delta&\rightarrow_\beta\Delta\Delta\Delta\\
\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right) \left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)&\rightarrow_\beta \left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\\
\end{align}$$

$$ \underbrace{\color{fuchsia}{\Delta\Delta\Delta\rightarrow_\beta\Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta}}_{\text{I want to derive this} }  $$

$$\begin{align}
\Delta\Delta\Delta= \color{red}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}\color{green}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}\color{blue}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}
\end{align}$$

In the first place, I've been confused where should I start of  application(=substitution?)  in above colored lambda terms.

At least I can guess that in the first step, the red term can't be an argument of substitution.

So the possible patterns are as follows

1. plug $~ \color{blue}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)} ~$  into $~ \color{green}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)} ~$.
2. plug $~ \color{green}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)} ~$  into $~ \color{red}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)} ~$.

What is the correct order of $~ \beta$-reduction in this case?

Here I continue with the first option above.

$$\begin{align}
\Delta\Delta\Delta&= \color{red}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}\color{green}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}\color{blue}{\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)}\\&= (\Delta)(\Delta)(\Delta)\\
&= (\Delta) \underbrace{\left(\Delta\Delta\Delta \right)}_{ \color{blue}{\text{b}}~\text{to}~\color{green}{\text{g}}  }\\&= \underbrace{\left( \lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right)\left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right) \right)}_{\text{An order problem arises again} } \\&= \left(\lambda x ~.~x~x~x \right) \left(\Delta\Delta\Delta \right)\\&= \left(\Delta\Delta\Delta \right)\left(\Delta\Delta\Delta \right)\left(\Delta\Delta\Delta \right)\\&\neq \Delta\Delta\Delta\Delta
\end{align}$$

I need your help.

Comment: From the wikipedia, 

***Applications are assumed to be left associative: M N P may be written instead of ((M N) P)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are important in λ-calculus, because $(f g) h$ is different from $f (g h)$ in most cases. Usually parentheses are omitted, in which case one means the first of the two variants. (See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Notation))
So the convention is to choose the second option which you listed.